# How to merge two elements within a tuple in Haskell

Tags: haskell

I'm new to Haskell, and was trying to merge strings within a tuple into one element. For example, if my input was ("Hello","world",1), it would output ("Hello world",1)

Comment: What is not working with your attempt?

Comment: Please provide an example of what you've already done before asking for a solution. For now, http://idownvotedbecau.se/noattempt/ .

Comment: So, you want a function of type `(String, String, a) -> (String, a)`?

Comment: `f (x, y, z) = (x ++ " " ++ y, z)`

Answer (score 2):

Not sure if this is exactly what you're looking for, but to turn a tuple (String, String, Integer) into a tuple (String, Integer), you can use this:

```
mergeStrings(s1, s2, i) = (s1 ++ " " ++ s2, i)
```

Now,

```
mergeString("Hello", "world", 1)
```

gives

```
("Hello world", 1)
```